# Replace array values with converted data?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have this array of time values:

```
["00:04:48.563044", "00:05:29.835918", "00:09:38.622569"]
```

But I need to pass each array item through a parser (in this case, [chronic_duration](https://github.com/hpoydar/chronic_duration)), and then spit it back out in to an array.

So each array item would need to get passed through:

```
ChronicDuration.parse('00:04:48.563044')
```

And then put back in an array:

```
[288.563044, 329.835918, 578.622569]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two obvious options; new array, or in-place.

```
pry(main)> arr = ["00:04:48.563044", "00:05:29.835918", "00:09:38.622569"];
pry(main)> arr.collect! { |s| ChronicDuration.parse s }
=> [288.563044, 329.835918, 578.622569]
```

To create a new array, leave off the exclamation point (`"!"`) on the `collect` call:

```
pry(main)> new_arr = arr.collect { |s| ChronicDuration.parse s }
```

You might want to map from one to the other:

```
pry(main)> h = Hash[arr.collect { |s| [s, ChronicDuration.parse(s)] }]
=> {"00:04:48.563044"=>288.563044,
 "00:05:29.835918"=>329.835918,
 "00:09:38.622569"=>578.622569}
```

Or switch the keys/values to allow easy sorting; either switching the `collect` array, or inverting:

```
pry(main)> h.invert.keys.sort.each_with_index {|k, i| puts "#{i+1}: #{h[k]}"}
1: 00:04:48.563044
2: 00:05:29.835918
3: 00:09:38.622569
```